# Using Find in a range in an excel

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have one excel (oSht loading), and in cell B67 I have "mystr" text and cell B110 also.

When i run this VBS code:

```
Set Excel = CreateObject("Excel.application")
Excel.Workbooks.Open "C:\...\...\Desktop\myExcel.xls"
Set oSht = Excel.Worksheets("mysheet")
Set aCell = oSht.Range("B110:B111").Find("mystr")
```

aCell.row is 67 instead of 110, why?

Comment: I just tried this myself and had no problems. I create a new workbook, and put "mystr" in `B67` and `B110`, then ran this code and it came back with row `110`. Is there some other code that might be messing with this?

Comment: No, there is no more code.  When i run:      `Set aCell = oSht.Range("B158:B159").Find(strSearch("otherstr")`    aCell.row is 158 and is ok.

Comment: What do you mean by `osht loading`? Is `oSht` set to the correct sheet? Edit: is `mystr` a string, variable or named range?

Comment: Yes, I've already checked that

Comment: There has to be more code.  Whether in VBS/WSH or Excel VBA (Alt+F11), the code you provided is not sufficient to run.  It needs to be wrapped in a Sub (Excel), a Function (Excel), or some kind of setup (if VBS).

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code? (I know you said there's no more code, but there's at *least* a line setting the `oSht` to a worksheet).

Comment: What @Marc said. If you can check that the correct sheet is set, that's at least one more line of code...

Comment: lol that edit. Why so obtuse.

Comment: @findwindow ???????????

Comment: Took you multiple edits to enter four lines of code XD I made that comment after first edit. Even then, I think I speak for everyone that you are still withholding code so can't help you :/

Comment: @findwindow do you answer users questions for laughing at them?

Comment: Uh where did I laugh at you? You still haven't answered my question above. And as others have pointed out, you're not giving us enough information for us to help you. You're making this difficult for no apparent reason. Edit: Oh, that lol. Like I said, that was made after your first edit. I apologize for the lol.

Comment: If you are using `Range("B110:B111").` but getting a row number of 67 as a result, it is very evident the code you are providing is not the complete code

Comment: @Davesexcel exactly. And OP continues to refuse to provide rest of code XD

Comment: I dont ocult code. I close the question so @findwindow stops laughing at me

Comment: @findwindow isn't laughing at you.  We're all trying to help you out.  You've posted code that, by all means, *should* work - but it's not.  Therefore, we believe you're not including some code (or some other detail) that's preventing the row to work properly.  One of the edits added code, which is good, but left a gap in the code (how did you set `oSht`). I highly recommend reading [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a question. It'll help you help us.

Answer (score 1):

With the little code you've given, I'm going to guess your error is due to how you're setting `oSht`.  Try this and let me know what happens...

```
Set Excel = CreateObject("Excel.application")
Excel.Workbooks.Open "C:\...\...\Desktop\myExcel.xls"
Set oSht = Activeworkbook.Sheets("mysheet") 
Set aCell = oSht.Range("B110:B111").Find("mystr")
```

*Make sure* that your `...\Desktop\myExcel.xls` has a worksheet called "mysheet" and *no other open workbook* has the same.

What is the `aCell.row` then?

Another option to check the code generally, is to close all Excel workbooks.  Open `myExcel.xls` by itself, then just add this code, and let me know what the result is:

```
Sub test()
Dim aCell as Range
Set aCell = Range("B110:B111").Find(what:="mystr")
Debug.print aCell.row
End Sub
```